# How to change active camera in after effects ( or render a different camera )

Tags: after-effects, camera, animation-rendering

I added a camera to my comp, however, when I render it uses the active camera, and not camera1. How do I Either make camera1 my active camera, or make it so that I can render out camera1

Comment: Also - a mistake I just made - the Camera must be visible in the Comp layers!

Answer (score 8):

Just move the camera to the top of the composition. The 1st camera is the one Ae will render.

Comment: Its worth having a look at this tutorial about [Render Order within After Effects](http://ae.tutsplus.com/articles/in-depth/understanding-the-render-order-in-after-effects/).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you've switched over to Active Camera in your Composition window.

You may need to switch the Composition viewport window to the camera you wish to use. Do this by selecting the camera in the dropdown menu at the bottom of the Composition window.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Parker Young, that's exactly what I was looking for.